# Elasticsearch date_range aggregation performance benchmarks

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a quick question. Are they any benchmarks done on Elasticsearch date_range aggregation query performance on large datasets? 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

My specific use case is the following: I have about 500 mil documents a month, and I want to generate date histogram for past 12 months. My query is like the following (pardon the syntactic inaccuracies):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [
        {"term" : { "fieldFoo" : "valFoo" }},
        {"term" : { "fieldBar" : "valBar" }},
        {"term" : { "fieldBarz" : "valBarz" }}
      ]
  },
  "aggs": {
      "range": {
          "date_range": {
              "field": "date",
              "format": "MM-yyy-dd",
              "ranges": [
                  { "from": "xxx", "to": "yyy" }, #docs within last week
                  { "from": "xxx", "to": "yyy" }, #from last week till 2 weeks ago
                  { "from": "xxx", "to": "yyy" }, #from 2 weeks ago till 1 month ago
                  { "from": "xxx", "to": "yyy" }, #from 1 month ago till 2 months ago 
                  { "from": "xxx", "to": "yyy" }, #from 2 months ago till 3 months ago 
                  { "from": "xxx", "to": "yyy" }, #from 3 months ago till 1 year ago 
              ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I am planning to do some testing and extrapolation on my own anyway but I figured I also want to survey if there are any similar benchmarks available.

ADDENDUM:
Also, my goal is to be able get response on those queries in less than 15-20 ms. So, I am trying to est maximum number of documents each shard can handle to respond within that threshold.

Comment: Does your index change a lot? Especially, does your old data change?

Comment: Old data may change but very rare, I estimate at most 5% of documents will need updating at some point after initial index.

Comment: @hummingV , Were you able to find some solution through Elastic Search or used something else  ? I have a similar problem and looking for the right data store  for good aggregation performance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take advantage of the [shard request cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shard-request-cache.html) by indexing "hot" data on a diferent index, as elastic allows you to search across multiple indices.

Keep in mind that every time a shard changes, its cache gets invalidated.

You may use a time based pattern for your indices:

- data_2018-01
- data_2018-02

And then search using *:

```
GET /data*/type/_search
```